# Добавление таких блоков через WP

Tags: php, wordpress

Нужно добавлять такие блоки через админку, с чередованием расположения картинки. Как это реализовать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой редактор используете?

Comment: Sublime text 3)

Comment: Какой визуальный редактор(или конструктор или т.д.) используете в админ панели для заполнения данной страницы?

Comment: А, вы об этом. Чистый ACF и ничего более.